# Javascript slideshow not working - Appearance is incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some issues with a slideshow banner for the top of my webpage. I tried following the W3 tutorial on it but not having much luck. So, below is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="slide-content" style="max-width:1000px"> <img class="slidepic" src="testheadphoto.jpg" style="width:100%" border="0" /> <img class="slidepic" src="testphototwo.jpg" style="width:100%" border="0" /> 
  <div class="slide-center slide-section slide-large slide-text-white slide-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%"> 
    <div class="slide-left slide-padding-left slide-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>

    <div class="slide-right slide-padding-right slide-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10095;</div>

<span class="slide-stamp demo slide-border slide-transparent slide-hover-white" _="_" span="span"> <span class="slide-stamp demo slide-border slide-transparent slide-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span> <span class="slide-stamp demo slide-border slide-transparent slide-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span> </span> </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide {

    display:none;

}

.slide-left, .slide-right, .slide-stamp {

    cursor: pointer;

}

.slide-stamp {

    height: 13px;

    width: 13px;

    padding: 0;

}
```

Javascript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slidepic");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" slide-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " slide-white";
}
```

At the moment, the two images are both appearing on the page at the same time and the arrows for right and left are below them. When you click an arrow, one of the pictures disappears and the slide effectively does work. It doesn't look how it's supposed to though. I've attached two images (One of how the slide should look and the other, how mine looks. As always, any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

[image: Working image]

[image: Not Working Image]

Comment: did you link `http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css` in the head of HTML?

Comment: You've got a broken markup. Validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are line breaking because the container is not setup right.

In your CSS, try:

```
.slide-content {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I also recommend putting your controls into this same container and positioning them absolutely to their respective corners, with a z-index set to ensure they'll be on top of the images that are sliding in.